# Laravel route using dynamic slugs for category, sub-category and more deeper

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have created a blog application which works fine and I am using only two-level-deep routing using servants as below:

`www.site.com/{parent-category}/{sub-category}/{post}`

I'm running into a problem because some categories will have more sub-categories and go deeper. A method in a controller becomes large and difficult to understand.

**Currently my URL structure is like this:**

`www.site.com/cancer/symptoms/<post-name>`

```
Route::get('/{parent?}/{child?}/{post?}', [WebSiteController::class, 'index'])->where('child', '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$')->name('homepage');
```

I achieve this by checking each parameter to see if it has a value and if it has a defined value, I load the specific view and model

```
public function index($parent = null, $child = null, $post = null)
{
    // If no slug defined show homepage
    if ($parent == null && $parent == '' && $child == null && $child == '') {
        return view('website.homepage');
    } 
    // Parent category is defined but child slug not. Show only root category
    else if($parent !== null && $child == null)
    {
        $category = PostCategory::where('slug', $parent)->where('post_category_id', 0)->firstOrFail(); 
        
        return view('website.category', compact('category'));
    } 
    // Parent and child category is defined. Show child category
    else if ($parent !== null && $child !== null) 
    {
        $category = PostCategory::where('slug', $child)->firstOrFail();

        return view('website.category', compact('category','children_toc', 'posts'));   
    }
    else {
            abort('404');
    }
}
```

**And I should optimize it so that it can be created like this:**

`www.site.com/medical/diseases/cancer/symptoms/sub-category/sub-sub-category/<post-name>`

I understand that I have to add for each category a parameter in the route and in the controller.

To route more subcategories, I would have to add more parameters in the controller method and do a check for each one, which caused a big and difficult to maintain.

```
Route::get('/{parent?}/{child?}/{child2?}/{child3/{child4?}?}/{post?}', [WebSiteController::class, 'index'])->where('child', '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$')->name('homepage');


public function index($parent = null, $child = null, $child2 = null, $child3= null, etc..., $post = null)
{
    if($child !== null && $child2 == null)
    {
        $category = ....; 
        
        // do somthing
    }
   else if($child2 !== null && $child3 == null)
   {
      // do somthing
   }
  // ...
}
```

**This can go on to infinity**

if I want to add another level I have to do it manually through the code. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Or is better way to store slug like full url in db column like:`/medical/diseases/cancer/symptoms?`

**Here is migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('post_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_category_id')->nullable(); 
        $table->string("name")->nullable(false);
        $table->string("slug") ;
            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel nested routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866831/laravel-nested-routes)

Comment: I found a related post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61866831/laravel-nested-routes

Comment: Guys you think i can achive this with binding route, and explode all params? I will try that example. by the way I found that post but I didn't try it, somehow it seemed unacceptable to me, I don't know why. Maybe that's the only solution

Comment: @Borjante no its not. You can check my name is Ivan as author.

Comment: Might be helpful https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#shallow-nesting . Instead of showing all the path just get the unique identifier and then remove the parent path. for example `/{parent}/{category}/{sub-category`} will become `/{category}/{sub-category}`. Then separate them in a different controllers or else you controller will be bloated.